# Stuck on Inverse Laplace transform, trying to convert convolution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-laplace

I want to express a convolution of a known signal $b(t)=c(t)\ast h(t)$ as an ODE $b'(t)$ instead.

The kernel $h(t)$ takes a double exponential form $Au(t)(1-e^{-T_{on} t})e^{-T_{off} t}$.

After rearranging and doing Laplace transforms, I get a lone $s$ term, the inverse of which I understand would be $\delta'(t)+\delta(0)$.
This ends up on the right hand side of $\beta'=b''$:

$$\beta' = \dots - b(0)(\delta'(t)+\delta(0))$$

Is my cause hopeless at this point?

Here is my work in detail:

[image: detailed work 1/3]
[image: detailed work 2/3]
[image: detailed work 3/3]

**EDIT**:

DinosaurEgg solved it! Looks like I was close, but missing two pieces:

1. I got $H(S)$ wrong, by forgetting the minus sign, I got $2s+\lambda+\kappa$ on top instead of $\lambda-\kappa$.
2. It didn't occur to me to simply assume $b(0)=b'(0)=0$. This works just fine. In the screenshot below, you can see the ODE solution is a little bit off at the beginning when that assumption is violated (look at $b_\text{conv}/b_\text{ode}$), but quickly corrects itself.

[image: comparing convolution to ODE solutions]

Comment: Is $u(t)$ the unit step function?

Comment: It is also helpful if you show some work as it shows you have put some effort, and also helps others identify any mistakes along the way.

Comment: Yes, $u(t)$ is the unit step function. I'll attach screenshots with my work--it was a lot to try to format right with MathJax, after having struggled to get it right with KaTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is actually quite a bit simpler. To declutter the notation a bit I will set $\kappa=\tau_{\text{off}}^{-1}, \lambda=\tau_{\text{off}}^{-1}+\tau_{\text{on}}^{-1}$
and then one calculate the Laplace transform of the kernel $h(t)$, which is

$$H(s)=\frac{\lambda-\kappa}{(s+\kappa)(s+\lambda)}$$

which after clearing denominators, gives the following relation for $B(s)$

$$(s^2+(\kappa+\lambda)s+\kappa\lambda)B(s)=(\lambda-\kappa)C(s)$$

The reason why we wrote the relation this way is because Laplace transforms multiplied by integer powers of $s$ can be rewritten as Laplace transforms of derivatives of the function. In your case, noting that $b(0)=b'(0)=0$, we find that from standard properties of the Laplace transform that

$$\mathcal{L[b'(t)](s)}=s\mathcal{\mathcal{L}[b(t)](s)}~~,~~\mathcal{L[b''(t)](s)}=s^2\mathcal{\mathcal{L}[b(t)](s)}$$

which allows us to write the relation after undoing the Laplace transform as

$$b''(t)+(\kappa+\lambda)b'(t)+\kappa\lambda b(t)=(\lambda-\kappa)c(t)$$